# Insert,Update and Delete Relationship in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've tried many ways to get my desired output but I always end up with errors. I attempt to have this 3 tables (tbl_inventory_products,tbl_inventory_tools,tbl_inventory_equipments)

[image]

related in one table which is the tbl_inventory_items.
Is there any way to link this 3 tables in one table? so if I Update,Delete and Insert New in every table the destination table(tbl_inventory_items) will be Updated.

[image]

if possible I also want to make the tbl_inventory_items to do the same with 3 tables. 
Every time I Update,Delete in tbl_inventory_items the 3 tables(tbl_inventory_products,tbl_inventory_tools,tbl_inventory_equipments) will be updated.

Also I want to fix the tbl_inventory_items where update in Item_ID is restricted only in Item_Name,Item_Description and the Date. I know it is very hard to understand what I want and also close to impossible but I really want to know if there is a way to get this.. if none Thank you.

Comment: I think you might want to redesign your database.  What is the point of having three separate tables?  If you had everything in a single table, you wouldn't have the issues about which you are asking.

Comment: Have you looked at triggers?